# Repeat Alarm called even time passed

Tags: android, alarm

i created alarm demo . In that demo i am repeating an alarm . I have one problem in my demo . My alarm called service even if time passed . I am setting 16:08:00 time and called that alarm so it called my alarm service after passed that time.Please help me to stop this criteria.

```
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)ctx.getSystemService(ctx.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 8);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);   
        PendingIntent pi = createPendingIntent(ctx);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000, pi);
```

**CreatePendingIntent Method**

```
private static PendingIntent createPendingIntent(Context context) 
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
        return PendingIntent.getService(context,0, myIntent, 0); 

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When setting an alarm to past time, the alarm immediately pops up. 
Simply check if the current time is bigger than the alarm time. If so, add 24 hours to the alarm time and set the alarm.:

```
long timeToAlarm = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
if (calendar.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis())
{
    timeToAlarm += (24*60*60*1000);
}

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeToAlarm, 24*60*60*1000, pi);
```

Comment: Hello.. i want to be automatically cancel alarm after 1 hr(Specific time)  so how i can do this ? help me please ...Regards,Girish

Answer (score 0):

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000, pi);
```

if you used the above code the alarm repeats at the  **24*60*60*1000** interval time.If you don't want to repeat the alarm then use the bellow code

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

the above code will cal the alarm only onetime.